# Can the occurrence of certain digits be proven/disproven, for any arbitrary irrational number?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion, transcendental-numbers

$\pi$ is perhaps the most famous irrational number. We know it contains all decimal digits from 0-9, just by virtue that all digits occur, at least once, within 32 decimal places:

$\pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950$ *(32 d.p.)*

Similar analyses can be applied to other irrational numbers, such as $\sqrt{2}$, $e$ and more. However, there exist irrational numbers that contain only a subset of the digits 0-9.

Searching the first $n$ decimal places of a decimally expanded irrational number is not a robust approach, as some irrational number decimal expansions contain only a subset of decimal digits, until $n$ decimal places, where $n$ may be a number so large that it is impossible to build a computer in this universe that can assist.

Are there any purely theoretical ways to verify the set of decimal digits that an irrational number contains at least once?

Comment: this is very vague, but as a general matter it's hard to say much.  For all anyone knows, $\pi$ might eventually come down to two digits.  Nobody imagines that is possible, but I don't think anything has been proven.

Comment: Most irrational numbers we can not even describe, let alone ask specific questions about...  Any irrationals you do ask about will need at least some sort of description to have any hope, and it will depend on that description whether we can intuit anything.

Comment: That depends on what way to define the number you use. For example, if you define them using algorithm (that takes $n$ and outputs $n$-th digit) - then no.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number is a similar concept, I will simply assume that much of what is said there applies to your case as well.

Comment: For some numbers there probably are (i.e. I can define a number that can be proven not to contain the digit $3$), but in general you can't. Containing all the digits (in a given base) with equal probability is called being normal (to that base). For most numbers (famously including $\pi$) it is unknown whether they normal.

Comment: It is CONJECTURED that $\pi$ , $e$ and every irrational algebraic number are normal , but in fact nothing subtantial has been proven , for example that $\pi$ contains infinite many sevens. In fact , every of those numbers might end with two different digits.

Comment: The final statement of my comment above is actually wrong - but mostly in a technical sense. I'm told that it is known that the set of normal numbers have measure $1$, so in a sense most numbers are actually known to be normal. If we restrict ourselves to looking at numbers we can actually describe, I believe the point still stands.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity This does not help anything in determining concrete numbers whether they are normal. We have absolutely no tool to decide this. We only know it for for numbers particular constructed for this purpose and for some artificial numbers like Champerown's constant. "Almost all numbers are normal" just means that we get a normal number with probability $1$ if we choose the digits truly random.